# Primefaces datatable inner join

Tags: join, primefaces, datatable

I got list of my Student class, Student have his own list of Courses. By Hibernate Criteria API I have selected students by name, joined Courses, so I have structure like this:

```
Student ID=1, Courses.size=2
Student ID=1, Courses.size=2
Student ID=2, Courses.size=1
Student ID=3, Courses.size=2
Student ID=3, Courses.size=2
```

Student is repeated as many his course's size. This is what I wanted to do. But I have problem with displaying it in my Primefaces datatable.

```
<p:dataTable var="student" rowIndexVar="row" selectionMode="single"  paginator="true" value="#{studentsMB.students}" lazy="true"  rows="30">

<p:column id="tematpl" headerText="Temat pracy dyplomowej">  
    <h:outputText value="#{student.name}" /> 
</p:column> 

<p:column headerText="Test">                                
    <h:outputText value="#{student.courses[???].name} " />  
 </p:column> 

</p:dataTable>
```

How to include an variable in "???" place, so I will can display name of each course ?

Comment: Isn't it better to get a list of Courses, joined with Students instead?

Comment: Unfortunately, It has to be the Students' list view...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the UI perspective using a primefaces [subtable](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableSubTable.jsf) or [rowexpansion](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableExpandableRows.jsf) would be 
better

For row expansion, a simple structure would be

```
<p:dataTable var="student" rowIndexVar="row" selectionMode="single"  paginator="true" value="#{studentsMB.students}" lazy="true"  rows="30">

    <p:column style="width:2%">  
        <p:rowToggler />  
    </p:column>  

    <p:column id="tematpl" headerText="Temat pracy dyplomowej">  
        <h:outputText value="#{student.name}" /> 
    </p:column>  

    <p:rowExpansion>
        <p:datatable value="#{student.courses}"  var="course"
            <p:column  headerText="Course name">  
                <h:outputText value="#{course.name}" /> 
            </p:column>  
        </p:datatable>           
    </p:rowExpansion>  
</p:dataTable>
```